# Can't connect to OpenVPN server, but only on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn, ssl

I'm using [PiVPN](https://pivpn.io/) on my Xubuntu server to create a VPN. I'm aware that PiVPN was designed especially for Raspberry Pis, however it's very easy to setup and work with so I decided to use it on my Xubuntu x64 machine as well.

Connecting via .ovpn files works flawlessly on Windows using OpenVPN connect, however when trying to connect on any of my three Pop!_OS (Ubuntu 22.04) machines, it just won't connect.

Here's the .ovpn file:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote myserv.org 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
remote-cert-tls server
tls-version-min 1.2
verify-x509-name myveryspecialx509name name
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
auth-nocache
verb 5
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
s0m3c3rt1f1c4t3
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
s0m3d1ff3r3n7c3r71f1c473
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
s0m3pr1v473k3y
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
<tls-crypt>
#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
s0m3st4t1ck3y
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-crypt>
```

Here's my syslog output on my Pop!_OS client when trying to connect via the network manager using the .ovpn file using default settings:

```
Aug 22 19:39:05 ben NetworkManager[821]: <info>  [1661189945.9755] vpn[0xd34db33f,blahblahblah,"blah"]: starting openvpn
Aug 22 19:39:05 ben NetworkManager[821]: <info>  [1661189945.9762] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="blahblahblah" name="blah" pid=31467 uid=1000 result="success"
Aug 22 19:39:09 ben nm-openvpn[31529]: DEPRECATED OPTION: --cipher set to 'AES-256-CBC' but missing in --data-ciphers (AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM). Future OpenVPN version will ignore --cipher for cipher negotiations. Add 'AES-256-CBC' to --data-ciphers or change --cipher 'AES-256-CBC' to --data-ciphers-fallback 'AES-256-CBC' to silence this warning.
Aug 22 19:39:09 ben nm-openvpn[31529]: OpenVPN 2.5.5 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Mar 22 2022
Aug 22 19:39:09 ben nm-openvpn[31529]: library versions: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022, LZO 2.10
Aug 22 19:39:09 ben nm-openvpn[31529]: NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Aug 22 19:39:09 ben nm-openvpn[31529]: TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET6]some:ipv6:address:1194
Aug 22 19:39:09 ben nm-openvpn[31529]: UDP link local: (not bound)
Aug 22 19:39:09 ben nm-openvpn[31529]: UDP link remote: [AF_INET6]some:ipv6:address:1194
Aug 22 19:39:09 ben nm-openvpn[31529]: NOTE: chroot will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
Aug 22 19:39:09 ben nm-openvpn[31529]: NOTE: UID/GID downgrade will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
Aug 22 19:40:09 ben nm-openvpn[31529]: TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Aug 22 19:40:09 ben nm-openvpn[31529]: TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Aug 22 19:40:09 ben nm-openvpn[31529]: SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
Aug 22 19:40:09 ben NetworkManager[821]: <warn>  [1661190009.4674] vpn[0xd34db33f,blahblahblah,"blah"]: connect timeout exceeded
Aug 22 19:40:09 ben nm-openvpn-serv[31515]: Connect timer expired, disconnecting.
Aug 22 19:40:09 ben nm-openvpn[31529]: SIGTERM[hard,init_instance] received, process exiting
```

Basically, the client just disconnects after 60 seconds complaining about a failed TLS handshake.

I can confirm this works perfectly on a Windows machine using OpenVPN connect and that port 1194/UDP is opened and accessible on my software as well as on my hardware server firewall.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds, my first guess would be that packets are getting lost somewhere. The configuration file and the log file won't reveal that. You'll need to investigate with tcpdump and/or Wireshark.